# How to create a new openerp field through function?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

I wanted to know if I want to create a new field then how this can be done. How to set the xml and other details .I think I will have to set them and return the field. But  is there any specific function to create new field ? . I have no idea .

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To create a new field to an existing object it's enough to inherit from the original class and to define your field in the `_columns` dictionary. Follow the steps below:

1. Create new module
2. Create a class in this module inheriting from the class you want to extend, let say from `account.invoice`:

   ```
   from osv import osv, fields
   class my_invoice(osv.osv):
       _inherit = 'account.invoice'
       _columns = {
           new_field: fields.char('My field', size=128)
       }
   ```

Next, you may want to edit your views to add the field somewhere etc.

Of course, you have to install the new module trough the admin interface.